# Android Studio Viewing more HTML files than one

Tags: html, webview, apk

I have added all the 3 html files I want in my app and when I "run" the app and click on the buttons that leads me to the other two HTML files it does that without any problem. But when I build the whole APK and dowload it on it goes to index.html (as it should) but when I click the buttons that leads me to one of the other HTML files it crashes the app and goes out of the app. Please help

Comment: Please, be more concrete in your questions. Provide some information regarding your code and errors appeared. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some instructions

Comment: I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597609/viewing-more-html-files-than-one-with-webview-in-android-studio